# Can't get AdMob to work (using Android, LibGDX)

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, ads

I've done a lot of research, but not much of it makes sense since I'm not familiar with placing in-app ads (this is my first time making an app, and my first time working with ads).

Here's my updated MainActivity.java code:

```
package com.me.mygdxgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); //Changed it back to main, got rid of an error

        AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.useGL20 = true;

        initialize(new MyGame(), cfg);

        AdView adView;
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId("My Ad Unit ID (just using this string for posting purposes");

        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.normal); //Changed R.id.linearlayout to R.id.normal. After looking at my R.java class, I saw that there was no id.linearlayout, so I changed it to R.id.normal, which did exist.
        layout.addView(adView); //This is line 44, where the NullPointer is caused

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

Here's the updated AndroidManifest XML code:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.me.mygdxgame"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/testing"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Flappy Nerd"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
             android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here's the main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/normal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the logcat:

```
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.me.mygdxgame/com.me.mygdxgame.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2359)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:165)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1326)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at com.me.mygdxgame.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
03-16 16:46:50.126: E/AndroidRuntime(10338):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
```

Here is an updated LogCat: When I take out the line of code that seemed to be causing NullPointers "layout.addView(adView);", the app runs fine, but I get these messages from LogCat:

```
03-16 17:04:06.723: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(11199): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.

03-16 17:04:09.265: I/Ads(11199): Ad finished loading.

03-16 17:05:09.269: I/Ads(11199): Ad is not visible. Not refreshing ad.
```

Comment: See the [tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) for integrating admob in libgdx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have missed the `activity` part for ads in your `Manifest` file:

```
<activity
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
   android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

You'll have to adapt all your routes to this. If you can compile but it doesn't work, you're probably using a deprecated version of `AdMob`. You'll have to import the `google-play_lib` external library into your project, [here's a link](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/) on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the google-play_lib, and I've added the activity part in my Manifest file, but I'm now getting new errors. Can you please look at my updated coded (in my edits) to see if you can find it?

Comment: And what's the error? Post your full stack trace. By the way, what you've posted is just the creation of an `AdView` object, but you're not placing it anywhere, so right now it won't be shown. You need to add it to a `LinearLayout`, for example.

Comment: This happens because you're including the same library 2 times. Basically in some step you included twice the google-play_lib library. Just remove one of them and the error should disappear.

Comment: In my Android project, I have "google-play-services.jar" in my Android Private Libraries, "google-play-services_lib.jar" in my Android Dependencies, and "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar" in my Referenced Libraries. However, I can't seem to delete any of them. Any help?

Comment: You just right click on the jars and click on delete. I recommend downloading the `google-play_lib` library and importing it manually in your project, by copying it to your project directory and then going to *File -> Import ...*

Comment: I already imported google-play_lib into my package explorer. Is that what you mean by importing it into my project? And I'm right clicking on the jars, and the option to delete is greyed-out and unavailable...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. The problem are the other two instances of the same library, I wonder why you can't delete. You can simply delete them by hand by going to your project's folder and then go to Eclipse, right-click on your project and click *Refresh (F5)*

Comment: Ok, I'm in my Workspace\MyProjectName-android\bin\dexedLibs...Do I delete "GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar", "google-play-services_lib.jar", or "google-play-services.jar"?

Comment: Thanks so much. Now I'm able to get it started, but it immediately crashes. I updated the question, and I added the logcat. Here is where the NullPointer is caused, according to the logcat :  "layout.addView(adView);"

Comment: Is there a `LinearLayout` called `R.id.normal` within your `R.layout.main` layout?

Comment: Well, I answer myself, there isn't :-) That's why you're getting the `NullPointerException`. Name a `LinearLayout` inside your main layout and it should work.

Comment: No, but there is a  "public static final int normal" in the "public static final class id" of the R.java, and I have a LinearLayout in the main.xml...I edited the question, specifically the LogCat.

Comment: I think you're missunderstanding how layouts work. When you are calling `findViewById()` you're trying to find an identifier that's specified exclusively in your **layout** file. That means that Android will try to find a `View` called `R.id.normal` in your `main.xml` file (because your set the content to be `setContentView(R.layout.main);`). If it doesn't find it, it will throw a `NullPointerException`, which is what you're seeing. You need to call your `LinearLayout` `normal` by setting it an id with the `id` attribute: `android:id="@+id/normal"`.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird because when I took out the `layout.addView(adView);`, the program ran fine, which led me to believe that it was the `adView` that was null, not the `layout`. Also, the line `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.normal);` didn't give me any problems...so if I add the line `android:id="@+id/normal"` into my main.xml, it should work fine?

Comment: Just try it, it should work. Once you get it working, both for reputation and feedback purposes, you should accept the answer from among all that helped you most, this will help other users to know which answer has been most productive for you and help them better.

Comment: I added the line `android:id="@+id/normal"` to the main.xml, and the program still gives me a NullPointer, which makes me think that it has to do with my `adview`. I think it's related to the errors in LogCat saying `The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.` I tried removing google-play-services_libs from my workspace, removing the references, and then importing it and referencing it again, but that didn't work. Perhaps I'm missing an sdk? Was I not supposed to delete `GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar`?

Comment: Should I add my R.java class into the question? Updating my main.xml doesn't seem to be doing anything, my `layout` is still null (I tested with a System.out.println), whereas my `adView` and `adRequest` are working fine...

Answer (score 1):

Your code is such a mess!

There are several errors in it you should fix.
To avoid errors your `setContentView(R.layout.main);` must be the first line right after the `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

And the most confusing one, to me, is:

Why do you have declared a `RelativeLayout` inside the App's `Manifest`?? 
It **must be** declared inside `main.xml`. This is the cause of your `NullPointerException`. It happens because `R.id.mainLayout` can't find nothing with this ID inside your layout, thus making `layout` variable `null` and when called causes a crash (cus it is wrongly declared in your manifest).

Comment: Yeah, my code is really messy, I have no idea how to work with XML, or ads. I've been working from the main project this whole time, not the android project, so I'm in unfamiliar territory.

It seems like my android project doesn't have a main.xml. Where should I declare my RelativeLayout? And can you show me how I should go about doing this??

Comment: You should declare your `RelativeLayout` inside `layout > main.xml` (it might be there, otherwise you could never referece it with `R.layout.main` when set content to the activity's View).

Comment: I don't think I need a RelativeLayout anymore because I looked at a tutorial and used some of the code from there. I made some edits to my original post, mainly in the MainActivity.java. I posted the new version of my MainActivity.java under my original post. However, I'm still getting errors. Do you know how I would go about fixing them?

Answer (score 0):

As @yugidroid, your code is pretty messy! :P But you will get it eventually, don't worry!

Most important thing, don't put layouts on your manifest, they don't go there!
In your folder /layout (inside your project) create a new xml file called "activity_main.xml" and fill it with this:

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

On your java file, change to

```
adView.setAdUnitId("xx-xxx-xxx-1234567890123456/1234567890"); //Change the numbers to what google sent you in the email!!!
```

and Adrequest change to

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

(not recommended for testing but for now it will do)

I recommend you though to read the documentation again though, it is pretty straight forward
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/#play
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play

Comment: I clicked both links and followed the tutorials. The XML seems fine, but I'm still getting errors on the Java code. Can you check my edits to see if you can figure out the problem?

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I didn't do what you said in your answer; I updated my question, with comments showing where I made changes. Now, I'm getting new errors...(this is just so confusing to me)

Answer (score 0):

I bet you are getting the NullPointerException on

```
findViewById(R.id.normal)
```

It is almost certainly to do with the #initialize method calling #setContentView and replacing  R.layout.main with something else.